# How to solve this memory leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

```
+ (UITableViewCell *)inputCell {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"id"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;  
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    return cell;
}
```

Xcode is showing a memory leak. I tried giving auto release during cell initialization and during return, but the app crashed on both occasions.

Comment: you must use an autorelease there. Can you post the code where you are using the "inputCell" method? I guess the crash is in another part of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted will leak memory because your alloc init will return a cell with a retain count of one. Presumably the calling code is then returning this object to a  [cellForRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acellForRowAtIndexPath%3a) which will attach it to the [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and increment the retain count again (to two). So when the UITableView releases it's memory, the object will still have a retain count of one.

If you tried autoreleasing the object in this code and it crashes, then you have a separate bug.

Comment: I have written the inputCell method inside a class named Utility. I am calling the inputCell in another class as      
        
         fNameCell = [Utility inputCell];

Comment: @Kiran Nothing wrong with allocating your cell this way (you do need the autorelease). So check what you are doing with that object after the inputCell call. Are you releasing it anywhere else?

Comment: No Im not releasing it anywhere

Comment: @Kiran In that case your crash is in some other un-related piece of code. Can you give us some additional information on the crash?

Comment: The app crashes with a SIG_ABBRT in the main function

Comment: @Kiran So you don't have a useful call stack? Sounds like memory is being corrupted at some point earlier. Perhaps calling release on an uninitialized pointer, something like that. Hard to tell without having a look at all the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"id"] autorelease];
```

should be fine unless you have a problem with the code from where you are calling `-inputCell`